# PHP5.x and MySQL : how to tell if a datetime in MySQL is older than now by a certain time interval?

Tags: php, datetime

Using MySQL and PHP 5.3

I have a MySQL DATETIME field called `last_accessed`. It is in the format of `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`

I want to check if the value in the `last_accessed` is older than 30 minutes compared to `now`.
If so, I want a variable called `$stillInTime` to be `false`. Otherwise, it is `true`.

I need to know what is the best way to write the comparison in PHP. By best, I mean most readable block of code possible.

I am using `date_default_timezone_set('UTC');`

The block of code should be flexible to allow for comparisons using units of minutes, hours, days, months, and years.

I have an attempt below:

```
public function isInTime($datetimeInMySQL, $intervalInString = '30 minutes') {
    $mySQLDateTimeObject = new DateTime($datetimeInMySQL);
    $dateTimeInterval = date_interval_create_from_date_string($intervalInString);
    $nowDateTimeObject = new DateTime('now');
    $mySQLDateTimeObject->add($dateTimeInterval);
    $stillInTime = ($mySQLDateTimeObject > $nowDateTimeObject);

    return $stillInTime;

}
```

This is my attempt to my question. I hope to seek a better answer through StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in MySQL as follows

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATEADD(last_accessed INTERVAL 30 MINUTE) <= NOW()
```

Comment: Thank you, but I want to avoid putting logic in the MySQL query. This will be my last resort. I probably *may* package the query expression into a variable to be used by my datasource object.

Comment: @kimsia - Why avoid logic in MySQL? The logic is closer to the data and therefore you get better performance. Better still if you use stored procedures as the only mechanism to access your database. This will make it easier to check your queries (as they are in one place) with your indexes. This also has the added advantages of having you business logic in one place and ensuring that your data is kept consistent. After all in a company the database is one of the most important asset and if it gets corrupted (i.e. inconsistent) it is very difficult and expensive to correct.

Comment: I am partial to the frameworks like CakePHP and Symfony hence, I tend to avoid putting logic in MySQL